# Replacing a Cython struct with a Cython class

Tags: python, class, struct, cython

I am trying to replace C-structs in my Cython code with a class to make it more inheritance friendly.

We originally have a struct like this:

```
cdef struct Test:
    double threshold  
    double improvement
```

which we then use in some Cython code like:

```
cdef do_something():
    # instantiate the struct
    cdef Test test, buff
    test.threshold = 0
    test.improvement = 0

    # you can do things like this
    test.threshold = 100
    test.improvement = 45

    # buff now is a copy of test
    buff = test
```

I would like to be able to do the exact same operations with a Cython class instead.

```
cdef class Test:
    double threshold  
    double improvement
```

This way, I can inherit from `Test` and create more modular Cython code without having to change many things. The issue is that now Cython thinks `Test` is a Python object?

Comment: It is a python object, and thus adds overhead (all above bigger memory footprint). There is no inheritance in c, thus in cython it can be only used with python object (cdef classes).

Comment: But cython now has C++ support, so ideally I would like to move away from the c-style struct (w/o inheritance) and to something that supports inheritance, but still can store the same type of data. Shouldn't the `cdef class Test` be a Cython extension type and have C++ like properties?